# コンマ区切りのテキストファイルから平均を算出したい

Tags: python

例

weather.txtに茨城の2000年1～2021年12月の月平均のデータがある。
年,1月の気温,2月の気温,・・・,12月の気温の順で保存されている。

weather.txtを読み込み、各年・各月の平均気温を出力するプログラム

```text
2000,7.6,6.0,9.4,14.5,19.8,22.5,27.7,28.3,25.6,18.8,13.3,8.8
2001,4.9,6.6,9.8,15.7,19.5,23.1,28.5,26.4,23.2,18.7,13.1,8.4
2002,7.4,7.9,12.2,16.1,18.4,21.6,28.0,28.0,23.1,19.0,11.6,7.2
2003,5.5,6.4,8.7,15.1,18.8,23.2,22.8,26.0,24.2,17.8,14.4,9.2
2004,6.3,8.5,9.8,16.4,19.6,23.7,28.5,27.2,25.1,17.5,15.6,9.9
2005,6.1,6.2,9.0,15.1,17.7,23.2,25.6,28.1,24.7,19.2,13.3,6.4
2006,5.1,6.7,9.8,13.6,19.0,22.5,25.6,27.5,23.5,19.5,14.4,9.5
2007,7.6,8.6,10.8,13.7,19.8,23.2,24.4,29.0,25.2,19.0,13.3,9.0
2008,5.9,5.5,10.7,14.7,18.5,21.3,27.0,26.8,24.4,19.4,13.1,9.8
2009,6.8,7.8,10.0,15.7,20.1,22.5,26.3,26.6,23.0,19.0,13.5,9.0
2010,7.0,6.5,9.1,12.4,19.0,23.6,28.0,29.6,25.1,18.9,13.5,9.9
2011,5.1,7.0,8.1,14.5,18.5,22.8,27.3,27.5,25.1,19.5,14.9,7.5
2012,4.8,5.4,8.8,14.5,19.6,21.4,26.4,29.1,26.2,19.4,12.7,7.3
2013,5.5,6.2,12.1,15.2,19.8,22.9,27.3,29.2,25.2,19.8,13.5,8.3
2014,6.3,5.9,10.4,15.0,20.3,23.4,26.8,27.7,23.2,19.1,14.2,6.7
2015,5.8,5.7,10.3,14.5,21.1,22.1,26.2,26.7,22.6,18.4,13.9,9.3
2016,6.1,7.2,10.1,15.4,20.2,22.4,25.4,27.1,24.4,18.7,11.4,8.9
2017,5.8,6.9,8.5,14.7,20.0,22.0,27.3,26.4,22.8,16.8,11.9,6.6
2018,4.7,5.4,11.5,17.0,19.8,22.4,28.3,28.1,22.9,19.1,14.0,8.3
2019,5.6,7.2,10.6,13.6,20.0,21.8,24.1,28.4,25.1,19.4,13.1,8.5
2020,7.1,8.3,10.7,12.8,19.5,23.2,24.3,29.1,24.2,17.5,14.0,7.7
2021,5.4,8.5,12.8,15.1,19.6,22.7,25.9,27.4,22.3,18.2,13.7,7.9
```

どのようなプログラムになるか教えてください

Comment: Baltfalt さん、以前の質問でもコメントいたしましたとおり、質問なさるときは何に困っているのかを教えていただけないでしょうか。Baltfalt さんがどこで躓いているのかの情報が無いと、どの部分について重点的に説明したら良いのか判断が付きません。また、解決されるべき問題が大きければ大きいほど回答を書くのにかかる労力も大きくなるため、結果として回答が集まる確率を下げてしまいます。間違っていても良いので、ご自身で何をどこまで試して、どのあたりで困っているのかを質問文を [edit] して追記いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 承知しました。。

Comment: 今書かれているのは「プログラムの仕様」であり、質問であるなら **何に困っているのか** が書かれていません。細かい手順に分解していって、どこまで出来て、どこが分からないのかを明確にしてください。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく「何に困っているのか」と聞かれても、「全てが解らない」としか言いようがない状態だと推測します。そうだとすると、挑戦の幅が大きすぎるという事です。まずは、やる事を細かいステップに分解し、一つ一つ取り組んで下さい。小さなステップごとであれば、キーワードで検索をしたり、このような質問サイトで扱うのも簡単です。

#### データを行ごとに読み込む

```py
with open("weather.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()  # 改行の削除
```

参考:

- [ファイルを読み書きする](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

#### 行を区切り文字で分割

```py
str_list = line.split(",")
year = str_list[0]
```

参考: [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

#### 文字列から数値（浮動小数点数）への変換

```py
for month in range(1, 13):
    temperature = float(str_list[month])
```

参考:

- [数値型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex)
- [`float`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#float)

---

これまでをまとめると、例えばこのようになります。

```py
with open("weather.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()  # 改行の削除
        str_list = line.split(",")
        year = str_list[0]
        print(f"-- {year}年 --")

        for month in range(1, 13):
            temperature = float(str_list[month])
            print(f"{year}年 {month}月の温度: {temperature}")
```

読み込んだデータをすぐに使うのでは無く、リストなどに保存していく場合もあります。今回はやることがシンプルなので、このままとします。

---

#### 平均を求める

平均は、

- 例えば `〜total` のような命名で変数を用意し、`0` で初期化
- `+=` などで要素の数値を加算していく
- 全て足し終えたら、要素数で割る

といった手順で求められます。質問のケースでは「各月の平均」が少し難しいかも知れません。1月から12月まで、`month1_total`、 `month2_total`、 のように12個の変数を用意するのはよくないです。こういった場合は、リストにまとめます。

```py
# 例:

# 初期化
month_total_list = [0.0] * 12

# 加算
month_total_list[i] += temperature
```

リストのインデックスは `0` で始まるので、この場合は月の名前と一つずれますので注意しましょう。こういった平均を求めるコードを今までのコードに挿入すると、完成です。

```py
with open("weather.txt") as file:
    month_total_list = [0.0] * 12
    year_count = 0

    for line in file:
        year_count += 1

        line = line.rstrip()  # 改行の削除
        str_list = line.split(",")
        year = str_list[0]
        #print(f"-- {year}年 --")

        year_total = 0.0
        for month in range(1, 13):
            temperature = float(str_list[month])
            #print(f"{year}年 {month}月の温度: {temperature}")
            year_total += temperature
            month_total_list[month - 1] += temperature
        print(f"{year}年の平均温度: {year_total / 12}")

    print("-- 各月の平均 --")
    for i in range(0, 12):
        print(f"{i + 1}月の平均温度: {month_total_list[i] / year_count}")
```

上記コードはテストしていません。また、[浮動小数点数の計算には誤差があります](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく初期段階であろう学習状況を無視して考えると、`pandas`を使うのが短く出来て簡単になります。
こちらの4行で読み込みと平均値計算が出来ます。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('weather.txt', header=None, index_col=0)
df['年間平均気温'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.mean(), columns=['月毎平均気温']).T], axis=0)
```

続けてこうすれば元データも含めてすべてを表示できます。

```
pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format
print(df)
```

算出した値だけを表示したい場合は、上記`print(df)`の代わりに以下のようにします。

```
print('年間平均気温')
print(df['年間平均気温'][:-1].to_string())
print('')
print(df.iloc[-1:, 0:12].T)
```